# PHP: Haversine formula gives HUGE (incorrect) distances

Tags: php, math, maps, latitude-longitude, haversine

Why does the Haversine formula return HUGE distances ? From the values that I'm passing, the distance should not be more than 1 or 2 kms. But it returns 8,104 kms.

I'm aware this is a recurrent problem with PHP.

Courtesy of the code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750275/haversine-formula-with-php) :

```
function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371)
{
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```

Comment: `I'm aware this is a recurrent problem with PHP.` Oh! What learned tomes teach you that PHP is incapable of doing math?

Comment: Your formula looks more like a planar calculation than Haversine

Comment: Well, its not about PHP per se, but maybe about the particular version I have (the latest one) or a mistake in the formula ?

Comment: Can you show examples of your input latitudes and longitudes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthMeanRadius = 6371)
{
    $deltaLatitude = deg2rad($latitudeTo - $latitudeFrom);
    $deltaLongitude = deg2rad($longitudeTo - $longitudeFrom);
    $a = sin($deltaLatitude / 2) * sin($deltaLatitude / 2) +
         cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) *
         sin($deltaLongitude / 2) * sin($deltaLongitude / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
    return $earthMeanRadius * $c;
}
```

A value of 6371 for the `$earthMeanRadius` argument (which is the default) is the earth mean radius in kilometres, which means that the returned result will be in kilometres.... if you want miles instead, then call it with an `$earthMeanRadius` argument value of 3,958; if you want nautical miles, change it to 3440, etc.

Comment: Hi Mark Baker. Thanks for that, but I'm afraid your implementation too returns a very large value. Is there a modulo or something ?

Comment: That is a tested and correct version of the Haversine formula.... if that doesn't work, check your inputs

Comment: Thanks Mark Baker for pointing that out. My input was indeed wrong.

Comment: And how to convert the value in Miles ? In what unit is the returned value??? Please clarify !

Comment: @PratikCJoshi - EARTH MEAN RADIUS.... A value of 6371 for the $earthMeanRadius argument (the default) is the earth mean radius in kilometres, which means that the returned result will be in kilometres.... if you want miles instead, then call it with an $earthMeanRadius argument value of 3,958; if you want nautical miles, change it to 3440

Comment: @MarkBaker  , Thanks Mark. But i see when i calculate distance , Google map difference(http://maps.google.com/) shows `0.069` miles where as when i use our algorithm it says `0.0601` . Is this difference ok(acceptable) ? Will this slight difference exist between what Google map says and what our code says ?

Comment: @MarkBaker , no issue sir I was using 3440 INSTEAD of  3958. 3958 gives me proper result

Comment: I've just realised for the first time right now that its terrible even at 100 metre resolution!!! I have pictures to prove it calculating distances along a roadway. I'm actually shocked by this. I'd like to know how postgis is calculating: ST_Length(geom,true) which is the spheroid version.

Comment: @EamonnKenny - If you need a more accurate formula, then I'd recommend Vincenty rather than Haversine.... the algorithm is more intensive to calculate, but it is more accurate