# Using ajax and json to ge the driving distance between two addresses

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps, distance, directions

Is it possible to use the jQuery ajax function and the Google directions API to asynchronous calculate the distance in miles between two given addresses? I've found a few examples that show how to do this using PHP, but nothing that doesn't require a page reload

Comment: Why not do it in PHP and use AJAX to get the result from your PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes just implement your calculation in php, and call your script asynchronously using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "calcdist.php?address1="+addr1+"&address2="+addr2,
    success: function(result){
        alert("Distance is "+result+" miles);
    }
});
```

and in your script (calcdist.php):

```
<?php
$a1 = $_GET['address1'];
$a2 = $_GET['address2'];

$ll1 = getLatLong($a1);
$ll2 = getLatLong($a2);

$dist = haversine($ll1, $ll2);

echo $dist;
?>
```

You just need to implement the haversine and getLatLong functions in your php

see [Haversine formula with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750275/haversine-formula-with-php) + http://code.google.com/p/gogeocode/ for help with these