# Mysql query for Lat/lng in range in java

Tags: mysql, gis

I have a scenario, I have users along with there address lat lng in my MySQL database, Now I need to get all the users who are within 2 km away from me (me as my lat lng ) 
I have one solution as I will get all the user's lat lng and apply #haversineformula and calculated distance and figure out all who are within 2km.
Is there any good approach as I don't want to fetch all the users and filter out them. 
If there is something I can do within MySQL only using some sort of query.
Appreciate any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553895/querying-mysql-for-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-that-are-within-a-given-mi

Comment: Why tag [tag:java] then?