# Read all elements from a Database table that are within a radius of 1000 meters?

Tags: mysql, database

A table with elements `(id, name, lat, lon)`.  Via a query I get the lat and lon of the user. Now I want to make a query against my database (`MariaDB`).  Give me all elements that are within 1000 meters of these coordinates.

There are ~300.000 elements in the database. My problem right now is that unfortunately I don't know how to make the query.

Can someone please give me an abstract sketch of how to make the query?

Comment: This article is about longitude, latitude and indexing, seems worth reading.    https://mariadb.com/kb/en/latitudelongitude-indexing/

Comment: please check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553895/querying-mysql-for-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-that-are-within-a-given-mi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying MySQL for latitude and longitude coordinates that are within a given mile radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553895/querying-mysql-for-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-that-are-within-a-given-mi)

Answer (score 0):

Use function below to get radius then check on the returned value

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetRadius(IN latitude1 INT, IN longitude1 INT, IN latitude2 INT, IN longitude2 INT)
RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN

/* line below represent the calculation to get radius using 
 2 points (latitude, longitude)  */ 
RETURN 6371 * ACOS((SIN(latitude1) *  SIN(latitude2)) + (COS(latitude1) * COS(latitude2) * COS(longitude2 - longitude1)));

END;
```

Assum that **latitude1** and **longitude1** are the values that you get from the user
and **latitude2** and **longitude2** represent the values in each record in database

then your final query should be like that

```
Declare @latitudeUserValue INT = 10; -- replace with user value
Declare @longitudeUserValue INT = 10; -- replace with user value

SELECT ALL FROM elements WHERE GetRadius(@latitudeUserValue, @longitudeUserValue, lat, lon) <= 1000;
```