# Ionic region search

Tags: angularjs, search, ionic-framework

I want to add region-based search functionality to my Ionic 1.* app. When a customer search for a store, they would get store (results) that are close to them, maybe a mile or two. 
Am using a PHP as my **api**

How to I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [angular's $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to make an http request to your api.

```
$http.get('urlToYourAPIEndpoint')
    .then((response) => {
        // append response to dom
    });
```

Some tips:

- Look into [angular services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to separate and organize your http requests
- Look into [angular directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to handle any dom manipulation

Comment: I know that. My question is, how do implement a region based search. i.e. search for stores close to my region with ionic.

Comment: @Ayo'Lana That's something you should do on the backend, ideally with mysql, but you could do it with php. Then return the results via http request. Look into the Haversine formula. This shoudl help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750275/haversine-formula-with-php