# Find if a point lies inside a Circle PHP

Tags: php, geometry

If I have coordinates of center point of circle, circle radius and also coordinates of the point that need to be check if a point lies inside or on the boundary of the Circle.

- $circle_x and $circle_y => center point latitude and longitude of the circle
- $rad => radius(Meter) of the circle
- $x and $y => latitude and longitude of the point that need to be check

I have tried 2 ways,

```
    public function pointInCircle($circle_x, $circle_y, $rad, $x, $y)
    {
        $dx = abs($x - $circle_x);
        $dy = abs($y - $circle_y);
        $R = $rad;

        if ($dx + $dy <= $R) {
            return "inside";
        } else if ($dx > $R) {
            return "outside";
        } else if ($dy > $R) {
            return "outside";
        } else if ($dx ^ 2 + $dy ^ 2 <= $R ^ 2) {
            return "inside";
        } else {
            return "outside";
        }
    }
```

Second method is,

```
    public function pointInCircle($circle_x, $circle_y, $rad, $x, $y)
    {
        if ((($x - $circle_x) * ($x - $circle_x) + ($y - $circle_y) * ($y - $circle_y)) <= ($rad * $rad)){
            return "inside";
        } else {
            return "outside";
        }
    }
```

But above 2 methods couldn't provide correct result, please help to find if provided point lies inside or on the boundary of the Circle using PHP.

Comment: PHP code is all correct but equation use may not be, (circleX,circleY) point of center of circle & (x,y) point is in circle or out?  if (d^2 = (x-circleX)^2 + (y-circleY)^2) >= radius then point in circle else not in circle. I think is the only check need.

Comment: what is the 'd' that you mentioned and can we pass radius using meters

Comment: if (((($x-$centerX) * ($x-$centerX)) + (($y-$centerY) * ($y-$centerY))) >=  $radius) {
            return true;
        }

Comment: above code is also provide always true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem on the earth surface with latidute/longitude coordinates, you need to apply spherical geometry.

[Look here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) at **Distance** section and modify code for PHP.

P.S. Found PHP implementation [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14751773/844416).

If result distance is less than your `$rad`, point with given coordinates lies inside the circle

```
function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```

now

```
if (haversineGreatCircleDistance($circle_y, $circle_x, $y, $x) < $rad)
    point i circle
```

**Note** - I supposed that latitude corresponds to Y-coordinate, and longitude -  to X-coordinates, as maps usually are drawn. Swap x/y if I'm not right

([Test here](https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/3342839)) gives OUTSIDE for small $rad and Inside for large radius

```
$circle_y = 48.8588336; //Paris center
$circle_x = 2.2769953;

$y = 48.80;   //Versailles
$x = 2.084;
//$rad = 1000;
$rad = 100000;

if (haversineGreatCircleDistance($circle_y, $circle_x, $y, $x) < $rad)
   echo "Inside";
else
   echo "OUTSIDE";
```

Comment: but i need this in PHP side can we do that?

Comment: This method also provide always true (inside)

Comment: @Shasika Madhushan could you show data used for checking?

Comment: $circle_y -> 32.809136, 
$circle_x -> 150.325108, 
$rad -> 5000.0, 
$y -> -32.8743, 
$x -> 149.8236

Comment: according to above data I need false result(outside)

Comment: Yes, code at my link gives outside

Comment: Yeah, my mistake I had use $earthRadius as my circle radius

Comment: thankyou MBo, it work like carm

Answer (score 0):

Broke down the code (partially the code you provided) into separate line to easily debug as needed.

```
function pointInCircle($circle_x, $circle_y, $rad, $x, $y)
    {
        $dx = ($x - $circle_x); 
        $dy = ($y - $circle_y);
        $dx = $dx * $dx;
        $dy = $dy * $dy;
        
        $dist = $dx + $dy;  //eqt of distance.

       
        $str =  "outside";
        if ( $dist <= $rad * $rad)
            $str = "inside";
        
        return $str;
      
    }
    
    echo " result " . pointInCircle(0,0,25,4,4);
```

Comment: The main problem - author uses  latitude and longitude as cartesian coordinates

Comment: This also provide always "inside as a return